# Name Tag missing in JSON generated by springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, spring-restcontroller

I am facing an issue with the code shown below. The below code is generating the json as follows :

> [{"id":123,"subjects":"English"},{"id":456,"subjects":"Maths"}]

We can see that the name tag is missing in generated JSON. I don't understand when I am returning Student List, the resulting json should contain the name tag since there is a property in the Student class of type "Name". Please help !

PS: I have taken the code in debug & I saw that "students arraylist"  0 index &  index does contain the name prpoperty along with id & subject. But the JSON doesn't contain this property.

Restcontroller:

```
package com.example.demo;
import java.util.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;


@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class Demo1Application {


@Autowired
Student student;
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();


@RequestMapping(value="/getStudents", method=RequestMethod.GET,produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public List<Student> getstudent () { 
    students = student.setStudent();
    return students;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Demo1Application.class, args);
    System.out.println("Hello");
}
}
```

Student Bean Class:

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Student {
    int id;
    String Subject;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("name")
    Name name;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getSubjects() {
        return Subject;
    }
    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        Subject = subject;
    }

    public void setName(String Fname, String Mname, String Lname) {
        Name nm = new Name();  
        name = nm.setfullname(Fname,Mname,Lname) ;
    }

    public Student(int id, String Subject) {
        this.id = id;
        this.Subject = Subject;
    }

    public Student() {
        System.out.println("Student Object created");
    }

    public List<Student> setStudent() {
        List<Student> Students = new ArrayList<>(); 
        Student s = new Student ();
        Student s1 = new Student ();


        s.setId(123);
        s.setSubject("English");
        s.setName("Hemant", "123", "Mamod");

        s1.setId(456);
        s1.setSubject("Maths");
        s1.setName("Akshay", "123", "pandey");

        Students.add(s);
        Students.add(s1);
        return Students;
      }
    }
```

Name Bean Class:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Qualifier("name")
public class Name {
    String Firstname;
    String Middlename;
    String Lastname;

    public Name() {
        System.out.println("Name Object created");
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return Firstname;
    }
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        Firstname = firstname;
    }
    public String getMiddlename() {
        return Middlename;
    }
    public void setMiddlename(String middlename) {
        Middlename = middlename;
    }
    public String getLastname() {
        return Lastname;
    }
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        Lastname = lastname;
    }

    public Name setfullname(String Fname, String Mname, String Lname) {
        Firstname = Fname;
        Middlename = Mname;
        Lastname = Lname;
        return this;
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you create a new `Name` instance in a `Student.setName()` method? Since a `Name` is a Spring bean an it's is autowired in a `Student` class it will be created within a Spring context automatically

Comment: @YuriyTsarkov Yes true. But by making Name.setfullname() as void & calling setfullname as name.setfullname(), I was getting Null pointer exception. so I did it roundaway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have not getter of the `Name` in the `Student` class.
Please add the getter as follow:

```
@Component
public class Student {
  int id;
  String Subject;

  Name name;

  /******/

  public Name getName() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

Speaking of `NullPinterException` with a `name` property - it means that it has not been autowired for some reasons, so in your case you can remove an `@Autowired` and `@Qualifier` annotations or figure out what is a problem with autowiring

Comment: Wow !! It worked like a charm ! But what changed ? I don't understand How a getter of Name made this thing work !! Please explain

Comment: The thing is that a `JsonMapper` needs `public` properties or methods to determine which properties must be serialized. So in our case we just added a public method and `JsonMapper` took an ability to include it into list of properties that have to be serialized. Theoretically you can add a `public` classifier to a `name` property and achieve the same result. Here is some information about the topic [Jackson – Decide What Fields Get Serialized/Deserialized](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-field-serializable-deserializable-or-not)

Comment: I am also facing some issue in deserializing . May you please look into this: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53571435/some-fields-not-getting-parsed-deserialized-in-json-in-springboot

Comment: please check the above link